# Actionscript 3 - Is there a way to save objects into array?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash-cs5

Is it possible to save a Sprite into an Array?

What i want is to automatically generate Sprites (by using a for loop) then store each one into an array so i'll be able to control them later.

So that i won't need to do this a milion times:

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
```

Comment: Can you be clearer? What do you mean by *"so that i won't need to do this a million times"*? And what will you do with the sprites later? Finally, how many sprites are we talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

```
var s:Sprite;
var sprites:Array = [];
for (var i:int=0; i<200; i++)
{
  s = new Sprite();
  sprites.push(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, declare a property `sprites` to hold the sprites:

```
var sprites:Array = [];
```

Then create the sprites and add them to the array:

```
var s:Sprite;
for (var i:int = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    s = new Sprite();
    sprites.push(s);
    // ...
}
```

Now, you can retrieve the sprites using their index in the array:

```
var s:Sprite = sprites[23];
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//put iteration no here how many you want

var no_sprit:int = 10;    
var sprite_array = [];

for (var i:int = 0; i < no_sprit:int; i++) {    
    var my_sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();    
    sprite_array[i] = my_sprite;    
}

// you can get these sprite     
your_sprite = sprite_array[0];
```